# READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE works on Android 7 but not on Android 10

Tags: android

My app needs WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and this code works without issue on Android 7 (API Level 25)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_PERMISSION_CHECK);
    else
        continueLoading();
}
else {
    continueLoading();
}
```

However, with the same code, my app does not get the permission on Android 10 (API Level 29).

I have the following permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What is happening here?

EDIT:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but the following solution worked on API Level 29:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_PERMISSION_CHECK);
    else
        continueLoading();
}
else {
    continueLoading();
}
```

I simply replaced `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` with `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: If someone can explain what's happening here, I will accept it as the answer.